# Trying to remove mouseleave using the jQuery off method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of buttons and I would like to remove the listeners for that button once it's clicked. Here how I'm trying to do so.

JS:

```
var currentBtn;
var selectedBtn = $("#moto-menu a");

function arrowEnter(){
    TweenMax.to($(this).children('img'),0.5,{alpha:1, left: -5});
}

function arrowLeave(){
    TweenMax.to($(this).children('img'),0.25,{alpha:0, left: -10});
}

function arrowClick(){

    // if there is a class to remove, remove it
    $(currentBtn).removeClass("selected");

    var index = $("#moto-menu a").index(this);
    currentBtn = selectedBtn[index];
    $(currentBtn).addClass("selected");

    // remove the listener from this button
    $("body").off( "mouseenter", "currentBtn", arrowEnter);
    $("body").off( "mouseleave", "currentBtn", arrowLeave);
}

// Moto menu rollover animation
$("body").on( "mouseenter", "#moto-menu a", arrowEnter);
$("body").on( "mouseleave", "#moto-menu a", arrowLeave);
$("body").on( "click", "#moto-menu a", arrowClick);
```

I don't think any of the off methods are working for me, just not sure why.

Comment: Is there a reason why you pass in `currentBtn` as a string, when you remove the listeners? Also, couldn't you check if the `$(this)` object is `currentBtn` and if so, not do the action? It seems like once they get unselected the arrowEnter & arrowLeave function should be active again?

Comment: Can't do `off()` that way....just check for a class in the event handler.

Comment: @Charlietfl - Thanks! I didn't even think of doing that.

Comment: Also going round in circles with the indexing in `arrowClick` to get `$(currentBtn)` because it is same as `$(this)`

Comment: Can cut whole thing down to `$("#moto-menu a.selected").removeClass('selected'); $(this).addClass('selected')`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery event delegation requires event listeners to be turned on and off using the same selector. In other words, you can't turn off a delegated event listener on just one element.

To fix your issue, you need to turn off the event listener, and turn it back on with a selector that will exclude your selected element. In this case, we have your class, 'selected'. So I updated your mouseenter/leave selector to include :not(.selected)

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/az8oh9ku/2/) - the fiddle has a few extra lines of code (commented) to help visualize the javascript.

```
var currentBtn;
var selectedBtn = $("#moto-menu a");

function arrowEnter(){
    TweenMax.to($(this).children('img'),0.5,{alpha:1, left: -5});
}

function arrowLeave(){
   TweenMax.to($(this).children('img'),0.25,{alpha:0, left: -10});
}

function setMouseEnterLeaveListeners() {
    var eventsSelector = '#moto-menu a:not(.selected)';
    $("body").off( "mouseenter", eventsSelector, arrowEnter);
    $("body").off( "mouseleave", eventsSelector, arrowLeave);
    $("body").on( "mouseenter", eventsSelector, arrowEnter);
    $("body").on( "mouseleave", eventsSelector, arrowLeave);
}

function arrowClick(evt){
    // if there is a class to remove, remove it
    if (currentBtn) {
        $(currentBtn).removeClass("selected");
    }

    currentBtn = this;
    $(currentBtn).addClass("selected");

    // remove the listener from this button
    setMouseEnterLeaveListeners()
}

// Moto menu rollover animation
setMouseEnterLeaveListeners()
$("body").on( "click", "#moto-menu a", arrowClick);
```